# What is the right answers of the seventh question of chapter 6 of Pointers On C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning C programming with the book Pointers on C, and have an issue about the seventh question of charpter 6.

If varaible h, i, q, x are all pointer to integers, and the addresses and contents of these variables are as below:

| Variable | Address | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h | 1080 | 1020 |
| i | 1020 | 1080 |
| q | 1084 | 1072 |
| x | 1076 | 1080 |

What's right value and left value address of `**h` and `*++*q`?

I think both expressions are illegal，as h and q are pointers pointer to integer, not pointers to pointer, we can not deference them twice. However the offical answer gives 1080 and 1020 as the right and left value address of `**h`, and 1021 as the right value of `*++*q`.

Comment: Have you tried putting together a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) highlighting the findings and debug it, step into it and watch the results?

Comment: @t0mm13b `int x = 1080; int *h = &x; (void)**h;` returns an error on any decent compiler, I don't think it can be debugged.

Comment: @DavidRanieri note that author of book is a CS. and it's a CS book, not a practical programming book. Published in 1997 year. It dwells into concept behind scences and gives some basic example of C design and usage with no attachement to the real language\compilers and applications. Instead it gives some understanding how a C compiler can be written, haha

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I know, I've read the book, that's why I say that the OP is not going to be able to debug it.

Comment: In 1998 integers where 4 bytes like pointers. ++ in a pointer add integer size = +4 to the value. You need to find an old computer if you want to test all this. And as already specified in previous comments, modern compilers will not be very happy with theses syntaxes.

Comment: @PtitXav an old computer and [one of these](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Borland_Turbo_C_1.5_for_PC-98_floppy_disk.jpg) :)

Comment: @PtitXav there is still a problem that normal C (and TurboC included) didn't implicitly cast an integer to a pointer. For `**h`  to be correct  `h` should be a pointer to a pointer. Aslo on 1998 PC those adresses would be virutal amd attempt to access them wuld likely go "nope". You need a 1978 PC for something like that.

Answer (score -1):

By modern standard they are illegal. `*h` produces integer and  dereference * cannot be used on an integer.

But let's assume we have a 1965-era naive C implementation and environment (some microcontroller) where pointing at any address is known to work, memory is physical, integers are cnvertible to pointers, etc.

`**h` equals to `*(*h)`. `(*h)` refers to `i` address, and `*i` refers to `h` address.

Now full stop. The right (column) value content of of `**h` is 1080, but the temporal value of the expression doesn'thave any predefined address. Most like author confuses himself and the reader, calling the pointer value (`*h` equal to 1020) in this case a "left value" .

"Left value" and "right value" are terms with particular meaning and the use above is not it.

Comment: to be pedantic and nit-picky, C compiler was not developed until early 1970, see this (no pun intended :) ) [https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html](C History) - would suggest to fix up the time line on it.

Comment: @t0mm13b And wiki is wrong there, or at least your interpretation. Compiler didn't exist as a finalized item until 1972/1973. But work on expanding B, creating first C prototypes and communication with  Niklaus Wirth happened before 1970. By the rules of 1970 what is written above is ALREDY wrong.